# Move Custom list form between environments(Dev, UAT, PROD)

Tags: list-view, custom-form, xslt-list-view-web-part, data-form-web-part

Environment : SharePoint 2010 Enterprise

I have created custom list forms(new, edit, disp) in my development environment. In the CustomEditForm I have inserted XSLTListView webpart(Child List) below DataFormWebPart and passing the ID of the Parent Form to the child form. I'm using Jquery to pass the ID to Child forms to Add new item link to simualte adding parent and child relation in single form. So far good...

For both the parent and child forms the list id is hardcoded. How do I move the custom list form to UAT/Prod environment because the list ID is different in destination. I used SharePoint designer to import files to list folder.

```
<WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart ListId="3d601950-2f74-4cb2-9052-4271f00952ba" ListName="{3D601950-2F74-4CB2-9052-4271F00952BA}">

<ParameterBinding Name="weburl" Location="None" DefaultValue="http://spdev2010:1200/sites/site1/site2"/>
     <ParameterBinding Name="ListName" Location="None" DefaultValue="Products"/>
```

Similarly the XSLT List view is also broken because it uses a child list id and view ID which are different in destination environment.

```
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ViewGuid="{B70E85B4-2BCF-4EB6-8316-B931AAB3F883}" ListId="1D321FB1-1BD4-4C08-8862-6263E3E70117" />
```

What is the best approach to move custom list forms for this scenario?